# Azure DevOps - Get the list of subject types which my ADO organization has

Tags: azure-devops

How can I find the list of possible subject types my ADO organization has.
Example of subject types I refer to are

```
vssgp,imp,aadgp,aad
```

Is there a way I can find the list of subject types in my organization `https://dev.azure.com/<OrgName>`